# Correct Push Varriable, and get Variable on Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

in controller i use looping foreach for push array in `$dataaray`, code push array like bellow :

```
$dataarray=array();
array_push($dataarray,"{id : ".$idjenis.",JenisPerjal : ".$Jenis.",JmlButuh :".$coba.",JmlTerpasang : ".$coba1.",Sisa : ".$sisa."}");
}
$data=array(
    'data'=> $dataarray,
);
$this->load->view('ExportPdf/exportpdf',$data);
```

i'm assum you understood for variable `$idjenis, $jenis, $coba and $coba1`.

result on view like bellow :

```
id : 5,JenisPerjal : Warning Light,JmlButuh :1,JmlTerpasang : 1,Sisa : 0
id : 7,JenisPerjal : RPPJ,JmlButuh :4,JmlTerpasang : 2,Sisa : 2
id : 8,JenisPerjal : APILL,JmlButuh :1,JmlTerpasang : 1,Sisa : 0
id : 10,JenisPerjal : Water Barier,JmlButuh :1,JmlTerpasang : 1,Sisa : 0
```

in view i can't get variable of

```
$data['id'], 
$data['JenisPerjal'], 
$data['JmlButuh'], 
$data['JmlTerpasang '] 
$data['Sisa ']
```

result in view i want like this

```
JenisPerjal   | JmlButuh | JmlTerpasang  | Sisa 
===============================================
Warning Light | 1        | 1             | 0
RPPJ          | 4        | 2             | 2
APILL         | 1        | 1             | 0
Water Barrier | 1        | 1             | 0
```

Comment: add arrays output of these variables `$idjenis, $jenis, $coba, $coba1 $sisa`

Comment: sorry not work sir

Comment: np i said show us whats in above URL

Comment: `$idjenis=array();` like this sir?

Comment: Yea you are pushing javascript objects, not PHP arrays.

Comment: You need to use array_merge - this will probably help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447007/using-array-merge-into-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your array like  below

```
$dataarray[]=array(
   "id"=>$idjenis,
   "JenisPerjal"=>$Jenis,
   "JmlButuh"=>$coba,
   "JmlTerpasang"=>$coba1,
   "Sisa"=>$sisa
);
```

And in view you can do like below, if you wanna display html table

```
<?php if (count($data) > 0): ?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($data))); ?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: that wouldn't work if he's using a foreach loop on it; it'd just overwrite 'id', etc.